# Ошибка при валидации xml и xsd документов

Tags: xml, xsd

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<!DOCTYPE file SYSTEM "ex2.xsd">

<file>
    <medical_record>
        <first_name>Иван</first_name>
        <last_name>Попов</last_name>
        <disease>Ветрянка</disease>
        <disease>Простуда</disease>
    </medical_record>

    <medical_record>
        <first_name>Алексей</first_name>
        <last_name>Иванов</last_name>
        <disease>Простуда</disease>
        <disease>Грип</disease>
        <disease>Астма</disease>
    </medical_record>
</file>
```

xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="file">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="medical_record" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="first_name"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="last_name"/>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="disease" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="reg-num" use="optional"/>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Ошибка:
The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed. [3] 
Ошибка возникает при валидации xml документа, при проверке xsd файла всё нормально. Ругается ошибка на третью строку xsd файла.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как английским по белому пишет что не нравится определение типа документа (DOCTYPE). По идее там должна быть ссылка на dtd.

На эту тему читайте: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp

Вообще это конечно проблема парсера. libxml валидация проходит.
удалите в строку опеределения DOCTYPE и валидация пройдет